# Binding JSON to Java objects with Jersey

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jersey

I am developing the REST application using Jersey and creating CRUD operations in my service.

My question is how to bind the JSON as an object in method. I am not able to doing the save operation using JSON request.

So please provide me any useful example which have developed the CRUD application.

Comment: If my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33626516/1426227) solved your issues, please accept it.

Answer (score 7):

[Jersey JSON support](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json) comes as a set of extension modules such as [MOXy](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy) and [Jackson](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson).

### [MOXy](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy)

JSON binding support via [MOXy](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy) is a default way of supporting JSON binding in your Jersey applications since Jersey 2.0. When JSON MOXy module is on the classpath, Jersey will automatically discover the module and enable JSON binding support via MOXy in your applications.

To use MOXy as your JSON provider you need to add `jersey-media-moxy` module to your `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're not using Maven make sure to have all [needed dependencies](https://jersey.github.io/project-info/2.22.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-moxy/dependencies.html) on the classpath.

With MOXy, you can use [JAXB annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/package-summary.html) to control how the JSON is generated.

### [Jackson 2.x](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson)

To use Jackson 2.x as your JSON provider you need to add `jersey-media-json-jackson` module to your `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're not using Maven make sure to have all [needed dependencies](https://jersey.github.io/project-info/2.22.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-json-jackson/dependencies.html) on the classpath.

Jackson 2.x provides a [rich set of annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) to control how the JSON is generated from your POJOs.

### Creating a CRUD application

Define a POJO which will be marshaled from/to JSON. Consider the following class as an example:

```
public class Book implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    public Book {

    } 

    // getters and setters ommited
}
```

Depending on your JSON provider, you can use annotate your POJO to control how the JSON is generated.

Create your REST endpoint. To consume data as JSON, simply annotate it with `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`. To produce JSON, annotate it with `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`.

Consider the following class as an example to start:

```
@Path("/books")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class BookEndpoint {

    @POST
    public Response create(Book book) {
        ...
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/id")
    public Response read(@QueryParam("id") Long id) {
        ...
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/id")
    public Response update(@QueryParam("id") Long id, Book book) {
        ...
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/id")
    public Response delete(@QueryParam("id") Long id) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show examples of how to consume these methods from url?

Comment: Note that there are 2 other options: Jettison and JSONP: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jettison https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.json-p

Answer (score 0):

In Jersey use `@Consumes` and `@Produces` to customize requests and responses.

Example: We have a Car object .

```
public class Car {
    private Long id;
    private String color;
    private int maxSpeed;
    private String manufacturer;
    //...

    //Getter and Setter
}
```

RESTful Service:

```
@Path("cars")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CarAPIService {
    //...
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("save")
    public Car save(Car instanceToSave) {
        //Implement method
    }
}
```

Yo can use any REST client to test this, as, for example, Postman.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html

or

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target);
```